# Don't submit email form unless minimum total is reached

Tags: javascript, forms

I apologize in advance for my ignorance... We have an order form where we'd like the users to order at least 6 items (not each necessarily but sum/combination of items that equals 6 or more).  I have it totaling the quantities up but not a working onclick/onsubmit function that can alert you to reach the minimum order quantity before submitting the form.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.  In lieu of posting all the actual code i'm hoping this is enough info to go on.  If not I can create some dummy text to apply if necessary.

Comment: `if (minSatisfied) { $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');}`
Disabled the submit button until the min is satisfied, then enable it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I'm such a novice I'm missing something... I used the following link to help me get the sum of the fields  [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript/) and then did the following to the submit button:
`code`<input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="if($('#sum')>=6){$('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');}"/>`code`

Comment: Maybe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/8d3N8/) will help you. Imagine the value of your input is the count or sum of items ordered. I put some notes in there to help you understand what things are doing.

Comment: You are wonderful, J. Wells.  Thanks so much for your patience and help, this looks perfect.  I'll work to get it implemented on the actual form but it appears to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks again!

Comment: np - let me know and i'll post an answer you can accept.

Comment: I got your code working perfectly until i tried to combine the orderCount field with some code that sums the fields that decides whether or not to enable the submit button.  I'm still too much of a novice to get it to perform properly in the fiddle so here is a link to my test page where I hope it's OK for you to view the source and check out what I'm missing. I can't express how grateful I am for your help and this learning experience. [link](http://serviceconcepts.coop/test2.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the inputs you want to tally:

```
<input name="LEDname" type="text" id="v8" class="tallyable" />
```

Then scrub and tally them up on keyup, then enable or disable submit if value is >= 6:

```
$('.tallyable').on('keyup', function () {
    var total = getTotal();
    $('#orderCount').html(total);
    enableOrDisableSubmit(total);
});

function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.tallyable').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().trim().length > 0) {
            var currentVal = isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
            total += currentVal;
            $(this).val(currentVal);
        }
    });
    return total;
}

function enableOrDisableSubmit(val) {
    if (val >= 6) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
       $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

## [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/8d3N8/)

Comment: This works perfectly, you are amazing.  Saved me a lot of heartache, so so appreciated.